# Reputation of meta SE sites and discuss.area51 not being counted

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta

I would like to know, whether the reputation change on meta SE sites are counted or not? Because, I don't see my reputation being increased on Unix.se, I received 4 upvotes on unix.se meta, but the overall reputation didn't change.

Similar thing for discuss.area51. Does the vote count reputation add to the main reputation on area51?

There is just a difference in badges for other child SE sites ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Meta sites except for this one use the rep from the parent site, so no rep is given on them specifically, just badges.